# MongoDB Replication with Ubuntu and CentOS not working

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, centos, replication

I am trying replication with MongoDB. The process is to be carried out on two different servers having different versions of Unix, the Ubuntu and CentOS respectively. I am facing various issues while doing this. Is this issue causing due to different OS. The replication works smooth with two servers having Ubuntu.

Comment: More information is definitely needed to provide any good feedback for this question, however in principle, there should be no problem having mongod's on different host os's.  Make sure that the versions of Mongo are the same on each server.

Comment: The replication could initiated smoothly. The cause behind the err was OOM killer on my VE by OpenVZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no issue with this. Posting mongod logs from both servers for the failing case would be a good first step for us to help you debug your issue.